# I can't export my excel sheet using VBA to the desktop on mac

Tags: excel, vba, permissions, save

I can't export my excel workbook sheet to my desktop. I can only export my sheets to /Users/elijah/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Document.

Not sure if this will help, but here is my code:

```
Sub ExportAsPDFTest()

Dim Name As String
Dim Preface As String

Name = Cells(1, "B").Value
Preface = "PreR Summer 2019 - "

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Preface & Name & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=1, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: This could be helpful https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/section3.htm

Comment: This website suggests what I have already tried - placing the workbook in `/Users/elijah/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Document` and exporting to that folder. This does not provide me the a solution to export the to any desired folder on the mac.